# awk - arithmetic operation, use different formatting in case field contains a string instead of a number

Tags: awk, data

I am trying to subtract data sets from each other in a single file. However when the script hits a value of `na` the output is incorrect.

Input file:

```
# <header>

2002    328     0.1345  2002    328     na
2002    329     na      2002    329     0.281065021
2002    330     0.9     2002    330     0.1
```

The awk script I am currently using is:

```
NR==1{print $0, " diff.\n"}
NR>2{printf("%s\t%7.6f\n", $0, $3-$6)}
```

which outputs:

```
# <header> diff.

2002    328     0.1345  2002    328     na      0.134500
2002    329     na      2002    329     0.281065021     -0.281065
2002    330     0.9     2002    330     0.1     0.800000
```

In this case to make analysis easier I was looking for the output column to show "`na`" as opposed to the value of the measurement.

Desired output:

```
# <header> diff.

2002    328     0.1345  2002    328     na      na
2002    329     na      2002    329     0.281065021     na
2002    330     0.9     2002    330     0.1     0.800000
```

Comment: can u check the edit suggested by guest...

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `NR>2` statement conditional, for example:

```
BEGIN {OFS="\t"}
NR==1 {print $0, "diff.\n"}
NR>2 {print $0, ( $3=="na" || $6=="na" ? "na" : sprintf("%7.6f", $3-$6) )}
```

- This uses `$3=="na" || $6=="na"` as the condition, i.e. `if either field three or six are "na", print "na", else print the subtraction`
- If fields 3 or 6 which are not a number might also be something other than "`na`", you could try something a bit more complicated: `$3 !~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/ || $6 !~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/`
- The above also uses `\t` as the output field separator in order to simplify some of the formatting